# Multiple select option boxes won't working correctly in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern

I have 3 selection boxes which called paymentStatus, orderStatus, deliveryStatus and those will update my database with values in options. In my code I cannot update my database without selecting values from all 3 selection box.If I select value from paymentStatus only it wont update my database. What I need is to update my database only from selection boxes what I changed.It may be 1 or 2 or all of them.

```
    const [pStatus, setPStatus] = useState('');
    const [oStatus, setOStatus] = useState('');
    const [dStatus, setDStatus] = useState('');

   const updateOrderHandler = (e) => {

        alert("Update handler working and passing data");

        const adminOrderUpdate = {
            'paymentInfo.paymentStatus':pStatus,
            'orderStatus':oStatus,
            'deliveryInfo.deliveryStatus':dStatus
        }
      dispatch(adminUpdateOrder(orderId, adminOrderUpdate))
    }

          <form>
              <p className="ststxt">Payment Status</p>
              <div className="statSel">
                <select name="PS" onChange={(e) => setPStatus(e.target.value)} id="format">
                  <option selected disabled  >{paymentInfo && paymentInfo.paymentStatus}</option>
                  <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
                  <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <br />
              <p className="ststxt">Order Status</p>
              <div className="statSel">
                <select name="OS" onChange={(e) => setOStatus(e.target.value)} id="format">
                  <option selected disabled>{orderStatus}</option>
                  <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                  <option value="Baking">Baking</option>
                  <option value="Baked">Baked</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <br />
              <p className="ststxt">Delivery Status</p>
              <div className="statSel">
                <select name="DS" onChange={(e) => setDStatus(e.target.value)} id="format">
                  <option selected disabled >{deliveryInfo && deliveryInfo.deliveryStatus}</option>
                  <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                  <option value="Delivering">Delivering</option>
                  <option value="Delivered">Delivered</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <br />
              <br />
              <button className="sbmtbutton" style={{verticalAlign: 'middle'}} onClick={() => updateOrderHandler(order._id)}>
                <span>Update Status </span>
              </button>
            </form>
```

in my actions.js

```
//admin update order stats
export const adminUpdateOrder = (id, orderData) => async (dispatch) => {
    alert("Action recieved" + id + JSON.stringify(orderData))
    try{
        dispatch({type:A_UPDATE_ORDER_REQUEST})

      const config = {
          headers:{
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      }

        const {data} = await axios.put(`/api/v1/admin/order/${id}`, orderData,config)
        alert("link sended" + id + JSON.stringify(orderData))
        dispatch({
            type:A_UPDATE_ORDER_SUCCESS,
            payload: data.success 
        })


    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({
            type: A_UPDATE_ORDER_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })

    }


}
```

I used alerts only for testing

Comment: You're spelling `dispatch`` as `disptach` in some cases.

Comment: Oh thanks. I corrected it. But that was not the error because I used same word in `async (dispatch)`

Comment: You may want to obtain the current values from the database and then set them as original values to your form inputs. So your inputs wont be empty they will have the original values. If the user changes one of them, the other two will be the same in the request object.